# Ordered relationships in SQLite-based Core Data in iCloud

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I have an iOS 6.1 app that employs a [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) model with some ordered relationships. It's next version should support iCloud. However, iCloud does not permit [ordered relationships](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-iCloudCoreData/index.html) in SQLite-based Core Data models.

Are there any recommendations by Apple on how to refactor the model in this case, or have you gained practical experience around this? I have one-to-many relationships between classes A and B, e.g. A1 to B1, B2 and A2 to B2, B3, so just adding an index attribute to B won't help. I may have to introduce a new class C with one-to-one relationships to A and B (e.g. C1 to A1 and B1) but would like to avoid this, if possible.

BTW, if I use the original Core Data model with iCloud I encounter multiple error messages of the following kind, which I assume are due to the presence of ordered relationships:

> ERROR: this process has called an NSArray-taking method, such as
>   initWithArray:, and passed in an NSSet object.  This is being
>   worked-around for now, but will soon cause you grief.

Answer (score 1):

I added to object property named order.

I have some object with "toMany" relationship with FotoContent objects.
FotoContent have property named "url"  and property "order". In my project I need to make them ordered by url name.
So let do something like this:

// without "copy" method you will get error message

```
NSMutableArray *fotosToOrder = [[[object fotos]  copy]mutableArrayValueForKey:@"url"];  
//sort new array by url attribute
[fotosToOrder sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSComparisonResult res = [(NSString*) obj1 caseInsensitiveCompare:(NSString *) obj2];
        return res;
    }];

//go through all sorted urls and add Order value to Fotos objects
int order = 0;
for (NSString *sortedFotoURL in fotosToOrder){
    for (FotoContent *unsortedFoto in object.fotos){
       if ([sortedFotoURL isEqualToString:unsortedFoto.url]){
            unsortedFoto.order = order;
            order++;
            break;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 & thx, but this won't help if a Foto can be contained in several Orders (as in my example: B2 is contained in both A1 and A2). In this case you need to store more than property value for order per Foto, so the question is how to do that. I am currently inclined towards adding a new class like OrderToFotos (or C in the example) after all.